# How can I 3D-rotate an image around the y-axis in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

How can I use Photoshop in order to rotate a bitmap image on the y-axis?  I'm trying to make it so that the right side of the image will go "into" the screen, and the left side will go "out" of the screen.

Comment: 1. This is superuser.com material 2. You're describing the Y axis, not Z. 3. turn you're image into a 3D Postcard in Photoshop Extended(3D > New 3D Postcard from Layer) and rotate it on the Y axis. More help in the manual: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WSCC5A0833-6F54-4dd5-A100-E3E93352CFA6.html

Answer (score 20):

You should be able to simulate the effect by applying a perspective transformation.

The option is **Edit > Transform > Perspective** or you can grab a corner with Ctrl + Alt and then hold shift down while dragging

[Source](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Adobe-Photoshop-1028/rectangular-image-trapezoidal-image.htm)

Comment: In basic CS6 I had to first dupe my Background layer to a new layer, then transform that. Then obviously ditch the original Background and Flatten.

Answer (score 11):

If you do actually want to rotate the z axis to create a 3D effect you must have Photoshop CS4 Extended or higher to do this:

1. Select your layer, then the **3D** menu (inbetween Analysis and View), and **New 3D Postcard from Layer**
2. Toggle the **3D rotation tool**, which is 4th from the bottom or press **K** for its shortcut key
3. Rotate away

Comment: This is the correct answer, at least for what "3d rotation" means to me. Clear and concise steps.

Comment: For those who don't know how to exit the 3D mode, in the layer window, you simply click another non-3D layer. To go back to the 3D mode, simply click that 3D layer.

Comment: **EDITED:** I found changing activated layer was not really correct. I still had 3D eyedropper tool instead of eyedropper tool somehow. I need to change the Window > Workspace to make it back.

Comment: **PS:** I figure out the best way to handle this is NOT switching to 3D workspace when the warning pops up and ask if you want to switch to 3D workspace or not when you first create the new 3D mesh from layer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a "lens correction." It's basically a perspective distortion. Go to Filter>Lens Correction

Answer (score 1):

If you have CS4/5 Extended you should have the "Vanishing Point" filter.  Draw a box around what you want to turn (such as a license plate) and choose "Return 3D image to Photoshop" from settings and click ok.  Then just scale it to size.  It will work on most any rectangular or planar surface.  We used it on a nearly side view picture of a car where the license plate was unreadable.  After this rendering we had a clear view of the license plate (minus some distortion from the bolts).  It was a near 90 degree rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Photoshop Extended version, so i use GIMP and this [3D-Rotation script](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25104) from its registry. In one experiment i had dy =-15 / +15 for the left and right image (dx, dz set to 0 as they're not by default), respectively. I then merged them in PS with copy-n-paste, with Mode=Lighten (Multiply seems to be ok too) and Opacity 80%. With the difference visible enough around the edges, i applied a Red-Cyan 3D script for a 3d effect.

Answer (score -1):

Edit - Transform - Rotate

Drag the little cursor in the centre of the image to where you want the rotation point to be.

Then drag the image around the rotation point by one of the handles or set an angle on the menu bar.

Comment: This is a 2D rotation; OP wants 3D.

Answer (score -2):

If you rotate a 2D image on its z axis,then it will become perpendicular to the plane of the canvas.

Thus the only visible image will be a line.

Comment: Well, he's not talking about rotating the image **90 degrees**?